# How to prevent flickering when drawing a grid with WebGL?

Tags: javascript, math, shader, webgl

I'm drawing a 2D grid in world coordinates in WebGL that a character can move over. For example, there may be a grid at position 2000, 2000 in the world, and it is 4000x4000 in dimensions. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Basically the issue that I see is that individual lines either render, or don't, which causes a jarring flickering effect. It's even more noticeable at higher zoom levels, because it flashes between a 1px line and a 0px line.

My shader code to draw the grid is very simple:

```
in vec2 v_world;

vec3 fgColor = vec3(0.675);

vec2 gap = vec2(100);

void main() {
  int x = int(mod(v_world.x, gap.x));
  int y = int(mod(v_world.y, gap.y));

  if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
    outputColor = vec4(fgColor, 1);
  } else {
    discard;
  }
}
```

What is causing this? And is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What is the unit of `v_world`? Pixel?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you cast the result to an integer, it doesn't mean that you can use floating point operations (at an undefined precision) and expect them to be strictly equal to a specific value. You're going to have to work a lot harder to make this work as you'd expect.

Also you don't show the rest of your setup, but multisampling for example makes this problem worse, since you start running into sub-pixel issues (if you aren't already, you really don't show much of anything -- I can easily imagine a world in which you add fractions of pixels to `v_world`). Remember that what `v_world` probably is is an interpolated UV coordinate between 0 and 1, multiplied by your canvas size, so precision loss alone can explain this.

The easiest way *by far* to draw your grid is to use a vertex buffer and build the lines yourself, then translate them in place modulo your gap. One draw call per frame, no buffer updates and absolutely no branches in your shaders.

Comment: `v_world` in this case is in world coordinates. And would that vertex buffer solution work in this case? Because the grid is drawn at a location in the world, if that makes sense. I don't really understand exactly what you mean by building the lines in the vertex buffer and them translating them in place.

Comment: No, it's drawn at a location on the screen. The thing about grids is that they look the same at (0, 0) or at (2000, 2000), they're just moved at most (`gap`, `gap`) pixels in your case, so simply use a shader uniform to store the world position, then in the vertex shader offset it by the world position modulo `gap` and you're done!

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is true.. Hmm, I'm still not entirely sure on how I would build the lines in the vertex shader. Sorry, I'm still very new to WebGL and even simple things like this are very difficult for me. Do you think you could provide some code on how you would achieve this sort of effect in the vertex shader?

Comment: You don't build them in your shader, you build them in a vertex buffer, the vertex shader just offsets them into place

Comment: Are you just talking about passing in a unit quad? Because I'm already doing that. It's what I multiply by my world transform to get it into world coordinates. Sorry, I'm just not following you exactly. I'm sure everything you're saying is 100% correct, but I'm just having trouble understanding.

Comment: No I'm saying you should make a buffer containing the individual lines in your grid as (x, y) coordinates. I know you're doing quads, it's extremely inefficient because you have to run your fragment shader for every single pixel on the screen *with branching code*. It's like layers and layers of bad.

Comment: Okay, I thought about it some more. Are you basically saying to just create a shader that draws a list of rectangles in a single draw call (instanced drawing)? And to pre-load the buffer with all the rectangles required to simulate a grid effect? And then do a single draw call to draw all the rectangles AKA the grid? And that will not only be more efficient, but also fix the flickering issue? Where each rectangle would either span the full width of the grid (and have constant height, a couple pixels), or span the full height of the grid (and have constant width, a couple pixels)?

Comment: And if that is indeed the case, is that really faster than what I'm currently doing? Like, if my map is 4000x4000 and the grid gap is 50 pixels, that would be 6,400 rectangles, wouldn't it? And if each one has an x, y, w, and h, then that's a buffer size of 25,600 floats. That's really more efficient than my above code which just draws a single quad and discards pixels that aren't relevant?

Comment: Not rectangles, lines (`GL_LINES`). And not the entire world size, only your screen size. Remember? Not half an hour ago I explained to you that a grid looks the same no matter where you look at it, so you only render one screen and offset it modulo your gap.

Comment: I thought using `GL_LINES` wasn't recommended because WebGL doesn't guarantee any line width more than 1 working? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447254/962155 So if I wanted grid thickness wouldn't I need quads? Also, with your solution of offsetting, wouldn't that mean we would have to rebuild the grid every time the user changes their screen size? Whereas not offsetting wouldn't have that issue, right?

Comment: There's no grid width in your code either, so that's a moot point. You are correct though, if you want line width you use quads *only for the lines*, not as you were using them for empty space as well. And no, that's what shader uniforms are for, you keep your geometry untouched and update the uniforms instead.

Comment: Yeah but I'm saying that I would have to rebuild and update the entire buffer for quads if I used the offsetting solution, no? Because if the user's window was 1280x1024, and then they resized it to 1920x1080, then there wouldn't be enough quads to draw, no? So you would have to rebuild the buffer when the user resized. But if the buffer was always the size based on the actual grid width, then you would only have to build it once when the map loaded, and then never rebuild it again, no?

Comment: When they resize, yes. Nowhere else though, which is why your consistent "I'm saying that I would have to rebuild and update the entire buffer for quads if I used the offsetting solution, no" keeps getting a "no". I mean if the user keeps playing with the size of the window more than you render frames, maybe make a more interesting application lol

Comment: Also, honestly speaking, your grid and UI and game world in general should scale with resolution, not stay the same 5 pixel circle at 4K. You get that for free with the normalized [0..1] projection space, and you don't need to rebuild anything to use it.